# Does this text make sense?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

I am writing a text to be sung by a small chorus for a recording, and I need a check on my Latin use, as I'm a less active student of the language than others, and don't entirely trust myself to nail it, especially when it comes to a more poetic context like this. I'll put the text in its current permutation as well as notes on what I'm trying to convey (will be English) & grammar functions I'm exploiting.

**Latin text thus far**

> OPERA CŌNFICIMUR
>   ET EGO AUGUR
>   CIRCUMĪRĪ ĀNULŌS
>   RĒX TITANĪ VENIŌ
>
> IN CLAMYDE CAECĀ TUĀ
>   HŌS TREDECIM ANNŌS ĒGĪ
>   ET CITAT TIBI ADESSE
>   CAELĪ FĪLĪ VENIŌ
>
> SENEX AD SENEM
>   LĪBERĪ TERRÆ
>   FRĀTER AD FRĀTREM
>   NŌS LIGĒS LANIĒS MĒ

**Ideas to convey in English** (as dryly as I can phrase it)

> The tasks have been done (completed)
>   and I, the seer, have too. (been worn out)
>   Circling [your] rings,
>   King of Titans, I come
>
> In your unseen cloak
>   I have spent these thirteen years
>   And it summons [me] to be near to you
>   Son of Uranus, I come.
>
> An old man to an old man,
>   Children of Gaia
>   A brother to a brother
>   Bind us together, tear me apart.

Notes:
Lines 1 & 2 both are meant as subject to "*cōnficimur*", each with a different meaning of the verb
Line 5 - ablative of place in which (locative)
Line 6 - accusative of duration of time
Line 12 - subjunctive to imply wish rather than command

There. Now tear it apart! I'm not going for poetic perfection (God knows I can't make dactylic hexameter work), but let me know if you think my grammar uses work or not, or if I've completely butchered an idea.

Comment: Does 'in your unseen cloak' in line 5 go with 'I come' or 'I have spent these 13 years'? Better punctuation in these lines would help clarify meaning. Also what does 'it' in line 7 refer to? The cloak? That doesn't seem to make sense. I also don't understand the last stanza. The only thing I can think is that the first 3 lines are meant to specify the identify of 'us' in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

## Lines 1 & 2

You state in your notes:

> *Lines 1 & 2 both are meant as subject to "cōnficimur", each with a different meaning of the verb*

However, if this is the case, then you should not be using *cōnficiō* in the first person plural. Furthermore, in your provided translation you explicitly state "have been done", indicating a completed past action, i.e, the perfect. As such, given this, and the fact that your subject is a plural group ("tasks" and "I"), *cōnficiō* should be in the *3rd person plural perfect passive indicative*, not the *1st person singular present passive indicative*, thus making lines one and two:

> Opera cōnfecta sunt
>   Cōnfectus et egō augur

## Line 3

In your translation, you specify that line three should be interpreted as:

> *Circling [your] rings*

As far as I can tell from context, *circling* is being used as a participle here, describing *egō*, the last stated subject. However, for some reason, you used the *present passive infinitive*, which is translated as *to be circulated*. Utilizing a participle, it should be:

> Circumiēns ānulōs

## Line 4

Line four is mostly fine, however, Titan is not in the correct case or number. It should be in the genitive plural. If you are using the form *Tītānus, Tītānī, m.*, then line four should be:

> Rēx Tītānōrum, veniō

However, if you are using the form *Tītan, Tītānis, m.*, then line four should be:

> Rēx Tītānum, veniō

## Line 5 & 6

Despite the incorrect labeling in your notes of a prepositional phrase as the locative, line five is essentially fine. However, your usage of the noun *clamys* is probably not right. It carries a very specific connotation, representing a cloak or a cape, but usually of a ceremonial or Greek military type (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clamys#Latin)). I would suggest the noun *pallium* instead.

Line six is fine. You did, however, incorrectly label "hōs tredecim annōs" as an accusative of duration of time. In this context, it is simply the object of "ēgī", indicating *I spent/consumed these thirteen years*. An accusative of duration of time would usually be translated as *for [time]* and is used to indicate the time spent doing something.

## Line 7

Line seven feels extremely awkward. In your translation you state that the direct object of *it summons* is *me*, yet don't provide this in your Latin, making it rather nonsensical. Furthermore, *adsum* doesn't really carry the connotation of *being near* something. Rather, it deals more with being present or arriving at something. I would suggest scrapping the entire phrase and going with something more like this:

> Et iubet mē esse prope tē

## Line 8

I'm not really sure how you managed to extricate *Uranus* from *caelum*. It means *sky*. *Uranus* in Latin is... well... *Ūranus*. Line eight should be:

> Filī Ūranī, veniō

---

## In short

To conclude, your full poem should be rendered as follows. You may have to make some adjustments, especially if you are trying to fit a meter, need a specific word order, etc.

> Opera cōnfecta sunt
>   Cōnfectus et egō augur
>   Circumiēns ānulōs
>   Rēx Tītānum, veniō
>
> In palliō caecō tuō
>   Hōs tredecim annōs ēgī
>   Et iubet mē esse prope tē
>   Filī Ūranī, veniō
>
> Senex ad senem
>   Liberī terrae
>   Frāter ad frātrem
>   Nōs ligēs, laniēs mē

Comment: Not so sure about all this. Liberi does mean "children", of course. And there is a lot more that could be said.

Comment: @fdb Ack! Don’t know how I managed to overlook that. Are there any qualms in particular that you have regarding my answer? Always open to improvements. :)

Comment: My problem is that I really don't understand what he is trying to say, especially in the last stanza. But perhaps others are more atuned to arcane wisdom.

Comment: @fdb I really couldn’t grasp the meaning either — my answer is mostly trying to criticize from a purely grammatical perspective.

Comment: I think caecus, used in the original version, is a better choice than invisus since, in my experience at least, it means 'unseen' about as often as 'blind,' whereas invisus means 'hateful' much more often than 'unseen.' Also, although I agree about changing conficimur to 3rd person pl., perfect tense, I find the masc. form confecti very odd looking. I'd recommend using confecta in agreement with opera, and then changing line 2 to something like 'confectus et ego augur' or the pithier 'item ego augur' (because otherwise, the fact that the 'ego' is also worn out becomes obscured).

Comment: @EthanBierlein Thank you so much for being so specific! Oh dear, apologies for leaving out the premise (shaking my head at my own oversight there)! A few colleagues and I are making an instrumental piece evoking the "Finale" of the Cassini mission to Saturn, wherein the craft dove through the planet's atmosphere and was destroyed. When the idea got pitched to add text (as if the craft were speaking some verse to the planet through the metaphor of the deity), it fell to me as the resident language geek to figure it out. As you can see, my skills are far from academically exceptional.

Comment: Ergo (ha), "unseen cloak" = gravity as bent spacetime; "Caelus" I had read somewhere was another Roman name for Ouranos (could be wrong). The last stanza is meant to highlight the link between Saturn being born of Uranus and Terra, and Cassini literally being made on Earth, and between their ages (Saturn being a first gen Titan [also the planet's some 4.5 billion yrs old] & Cassini the craft being in operation well after its original mission period). Thanks all for your input!